XRechnung Visualization Transformators - PDF generation not working
After I Installed Java and Ant than I go  xrechnung-visualization directory and run the commands, the PDF generated is not working, when trying to open it with adobe acrobat it says: "Adobe Acrobat could not open myFile.pdf because either it is not supported file type or because the file has been damaged...".
After installing Ant I run the following commands:
cd xrechnung-visualization
ant

java -jar lib/saxon-he-10.6.jar -s:path/to/Rechnung.xml -xsl:src/xsl/ubl-invoice-xr.xsl -o:out/Rechnung.xr

java -jar lib/saxon-he-10.6.jar -s:out/Rechnung.xr -xsl:src/xsl/xr-pdf.xsl -o:out/Rechnung.pdf 

If I try to generate HTML it works!

Ask the support for XRechnung. Do you have Apache FOP installed as well or how exactly do you expect to get a PDF from an XSLT transformation?

At best the second XSLT transformations gives your a FO file that you can feed to Apache FOP or any other FOP processor.

Specify what 'not working' means. Include any error messages or logs from the PDF generation process.

@MartinHonnen normally Apache FOP should be installed after the build I think,
IlyaKhrustalev No there is no error messages, just after opening the PDF file

For all who has the same problem this worked for me:
I downloaded Apache FOP and moved files to the ...\lib\fop
After that I used the following commands to convert .xml -> .xr -> .fo -> .pdf
java -jar lib/saxon-he-10.6.jar -s:path\to\your\Rechnung.xml -xsl:src/xsl/ubl-invoice-xr.xsl -o:path\to\your\Rechnung.xr

java -jar lib/saxon-he-10.6.jar -s:path\to\your\Rechnung.xr -xsl:src/xsl/xr-pdf.xsl -o:path\to\your\Rechnung.fo

path\to\your\fop.bat -fo C:path\to\your\Rechnung.fo -pdf path\to\your\Rechnung.pdf


Remember to use the proper xsl file for you XML file type:
for UBL Invoice use: ubl-invoice-xr.xsl
for CreditNote use: ubl-creditnote-xr.xsl
for Cross Industry Invoice use: cii-xr.xsl

